# How to change Highlighting color in CheckListbox

Tags: c#, winforms, checklistbox

I am working on a Windows Forms project, and I couldn't find any information that would tell me, how I can change the highlight color of a `CheckListbox`.

Does anyone know how to change that?

Comment: No. It's similar, but my question is how to change color of item you click on. So by default background of **Highlight** is blue. I want it to be gray. After you go on next item even if is checked or not, it goes away to the next item you will select.

Comment: you will probably have to do it on your own, programming the event OnDrawItem.

Comment: I know, any examples?

Comment: they are shown in the duplicate link, where you must adept them to your needs